# C# use dropdown list value to alter the properties of text

Tags: c#

I am taking a course in C# with .Net, as proceeding with the problems, i am developing a web-app, say displaying text "Welcome User" and i should be able to change the color of the text using a button, i can simply do that using the below code,

```
protected void changeColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string altertedText = "<h4 style = 'color:green'> Welcome User! </h4>";
wordHolders.Text = altertedText;
}
```

But, i would like to change the same dynamically with the selected user input, say using a drop-down list, the list has different colors - Green, Blue, Red and submitting it using a button.
I am not able to achieve the same using concatenation.
Where am i doing wrong

```
protected void changeColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string first = "<h4 style = 'color:'";
    string mid = colorName.SelectedValue;
    string last = "'> Welcome User! </h4>";
    wordHolders.Text = string.Concat(first, mid, last);
}
```

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No single quote after _color:_

Comment: Use `style = "color:green;"` instead `style = 'color:green'`. Better idea for changing color will be use JavaScript without code behind.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that extra single quote was the problem, its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

you could optimize your code a litte bit with this snippet:

```
protected void changeColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wordHolders.Text = $"<h4 style=\"color: {colorName.SelectedValue};\">Welcome User!</h4>";
}
```